# Is there a good way to test your schematic before buying the parts and building it?

Tags: batteries, analog, schematics, test, lifepo4

I'm trying to design a BMS that can handle 12 cells, be powered either with a isolated dc-dc converter or the batteries themselves and uses active balancing, but I'm not sure if my design will work: [image: Schematic]

Comment: Yes there are many simple ways to test your assumptions for part of the circuit to evaluate resonance, power dissipation and startup.  I use Falstad’s sim which demands skill to know how to model your assumptions for. The battery model, Trace inductance, cap ESR etc. Those that can do, those that can’t will,say no.  the biggest problem is you have no specs, like max Pd for imbalance bypass power and battery charge currents with voltage mismatch. Max temp rise, thermal safe margins etc.

Comment: After you define all these specs, then you can make a short DVT plan and verify on a simulator then on a prototype scaled down. then the final design ought to be “Right the 1st time”

Comment: I doubt your design will work to my specs, but what are yours.?

Comment: The best tool is the one you know how to use. I don’t mean basically, I mean master it. It will save you lots of redesign wasted time because of unknowns or unstated specs or misunderstood assumptions.  And of course Murphy”s Law. it happens to most of us, myself included, although I know some who had the experience to get it right the first time.

Comment: Why not make a SMPS  95% efficient balancer with a flying half-bridge chokes in cascade instead of linear loss bypass. Think about 11x 4.2V x Ichg watts wasted in heat when 1 cell is stronger than the rest and all the others in cutoff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not, computers will not be able to do the jobs of electrical engineers for a long time, if ever.

The best bet is to simulate the parts of the circuit that are most complex in a spice package. I would test the DC to DC in a spice package. If your really unsure, I would test only one of the DC to DC converters before building many of them.

Most schematic designers also have Design Rule Check (DRC) packages that you can check voltage compatibility, input/output compatibility, ect. to help the designer spot mistakes. This also takes a lot of time to setup.

A few other basic tips:

- Read the datasheet through for all new parts that don't have history (ie the circuits that are new to you)
- Check each part for bypass caps
- Check the pinout for all connectors and make sure they match the cables.
- Check every pin voltage.
- Make sure there is enough current/power for all the parts
- Check programming interface pinouts